# No matches for kind "HelmChart" in version "helm.cattle.io/v1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher, k8s-serviceaccount

I am trying to create jenkins from helmChart, I used this way a year ago and it worked but now it is not working and I got this error when I tried to apply the yaml file `kubectl apply -f helm.yaml -n jenkins`:

```
no matches for kind "HelmChart" in version "helm.cattle.io/v1"
```

helm.yaml

```
kind: HelmChart
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  chart: stable/jenkins
  targetNamespace: jenkins
  valuesContent: |-
    master:
      adminUser: admin
      adminPassword: admin
      image: jenkinsci/blueocean
      tag: latest
      jenkinsUriPrefix: /jenkins
      JCasC:
        authorizationStrategy: anyoneCanDoAnything
```

Comment: This might help? https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/helm/

Comment: No it desnt help, I copied their example but it doesn't work as well

Comment: Could you improve your question by adding the complete helm.yaml, describe what K8s cluster environment you are using and the steps you took to reach this stage. This might help others to help you more.

Comment: I was able to apply your file successfully - with ``helmchart.helm.cattle.io/jenkins created`` msg. To reproduce your problem, could you please give more details on your K8s cluster environment - version, is it in cloud/ bare-metal?